# Reuse Entity Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity

I am using Entity Framework to access my MSSQL DB. In the one function, the query is called twice. In the meantime, the according data changes. When I try to execute the query again, it still returns the same value as it did in the first place: (Umfragen is the class)

```
Umfrage Survey = await db.Umfragen.FindAsync(SurveyId);          
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("UpdateSurvey", ConnectionString);
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                   
using (ConnectionString)
{

      ConnectionString.Open();
      Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      return Ok(await db.Umfragen.FindAsync(SurveyId));                                    
}
```

The first call is needed for some parameters. How is it possible that it doesn't return the new value?
When I don't execute the first call and predefine the parameters, it works fine.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my question should be a duplicate, I couldn't find any other question with this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FindAsync` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246936(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbSet%601.FindAsync(System.Object[])) states

> Asynchronously finds an entity with the given primary key values. **If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store.** Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned.

In your case, the first call to `FindAsync` loads the entity in the context, so even if it is updated later in the database, the second `FindAsync` returns the same cached instance.

In order to refresh the cached instance, you can use [DbEntityEntry.ReloadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn177537(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry%601.ReloadAsync) method like this

```
Umfrage Survey = await db.Umfragen.FindAsync(SurveyId);          
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("UpdateSurvey", ConnectionString);
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                   
using (ConnectionString)
{
    ConnectionString.Open();
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    await db.Entry(Survey).ReloadAsync();  
    return Ok(Survey);                                    
}
```